# Undefined objects using Map().get() in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ternary-operator

So I have some `userObject` that has attributes

```
public userId: string
public displayName: string
public username: string
```

and a `productObject` that has attributes

```
public productId: string
public userIds: string[] | null
```

I'm doing this:

```
private _$customerUsers: Map<string, UserObject> | undefined = undefined

private _onUsers = (bundle: DataBundleObject<UserObject>) => {
    this._$customerUsers = new Map()
    for (let customerUser of bundle.listOfData) {
        this._$customerUsers.set(customerUser.userId, customerUser)
    }
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
productObject.userIds.map(user => {<span>this._$customerUsers.get(user).username</span>})
```

which I cannot run as VScode tells me `Object is possibly 'undefined'` so I tried ternary operators:

```
this._$customerUsers ? this._$customerUsers.get(user) ? this._$customerUsers.get(user).username
```

but it still says the last may be `undefined`. How is that possible? The second ternary expression should check if the returning object is `undefined`.

---

**Update**

Weirdly I can do

```
productObject.userIds.map(user => {
    if (this._$customerUsers) {
        var userO = this._$customerUsers.get(user)
        if (userO === undefined) {<Tag color='red'>N/A</Tag>}
        else {
            <Tag color="blue" key={user}>{userO.username}</Tag>
        }
    }
    <Tag color='red'>N/A</Tag>
})
```

but not

```
productObject.userIds.map(user => {
    if (this._$customerUsers) {
        if (this._$customerUsers.get(user) === undefined) {<Tag color='red'>N/A</Tag>}
        else {
            <Tag color="blue" key={user}>{this._$customerUsers.get(user).username}</Tag>
        }
    }
    <Tag color='red'>N/A</Tag>
})
```

something about it being a variable makes it better to evaluate.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler doesn't know that `.get()` returns the same result every time.

Comment: It does seem to know that the expected return value is `userObject | undefined` @SLaks

Comment: Is there some reason that you need a Map? Why not a POJO?

Comment: Does it say that `_$customerUsers` is possibly undefined? Because that's exactly what your declaration of `_$customerUsers` says.

Comment: @FranklinHarvey: Yes, but it's afraid that `.get(user)` might return a value the first time, but `undefined` the second time.

Comment: @SLaks I updated with a (slightly clunky) solution. Somehow assigning a variable to `this._$customerUsers.get(user)` is better to evaluate for `undefined` than the expression itself

Comment: Yes; that's because the compiler knows that `userO` will not change between calls, whereas it does not know that `this._$customerUsers.get(user)` will not change between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use ternary operators make this difficult, it works better by assigning a variable to the return of `this._$customerUser.get()`:

```
productObject.userIds.map(user => {
    if (this._$customerUsers) {
        var singleUser = this._$customerUsers.get(user)
        if (singleUser === undefined) {<span>N/A</span>}
        else {
            return <span key={user}>{singleUser.username}</span>
        }
    }
    return <span>N/A</span>
})
```